# 'geometry_msgs' depends on non-existent package 'message_runtime'

Tags: geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everybody,

I' m trying to install a packege but rosmake ends by this  error:

> [rospack] Error: package/stack 'geometry_msgs' depends on non-existent >package 'message_runtime' and rosdep claims that it is not a system >dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is setted on the packege path i'm installing and rosupdate fails by a 404 file not found error.
I did't find any documentation about  message_runtime package.
could someone help me?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61911/%27geometry_msgs%27-depends-on-non-existent-package-%27message_runtime%27/) by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Are you installing ros-groovy? Try installing message-runtime.

sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-message-runtime should install the package.

---

Originally posted by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) with karma: 358 on 2013-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-05-01**:
thanks for you answer. I' m already on groovy and when I try                                                                        sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-message-runtime      the shell tell me:        ros-groovy-message-runtime is already the newest version.

**Comment by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) on 2013-05-01**:
Try running rosdep update and restart the shell. I hope it solves the problem

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-05-01**:
rosdep update stops after the massage:      Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
ERROR: error loading sources list:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found

**Comment by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) on 2013-05-01**:
https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues/239 . Check this link out. I think so its similar to your problem. Try updating rosdistro